# Angular 2 without Webserver

Tags: angular, filesystems, webserver

How can I use Angular 2 in production without webserver and just the filesystem?
I can't use a webserver because of the corporate policies 
(that was not a problem with Angular because I could use the filesystem).

Comment: Do you want to use the app over the network?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: what are your use cases? xhr doesn't work in `file:///` protocol

Comment: I have this error : "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///[...]/src/main.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."
Indeed, I have this error because I don't use a webserver (when I use one, there is no problem).
The question is how to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need network, Angular (version 2 and higher) applications work with no problems over the `file:/` protocol. But you must set a correct base href path in your `index.html`. If you are using Angular CLI, you can build the app using the following command:

```
ng build --base-href=/path/to/your/application/dist/
```

and then opening the `file:///path/to/your/application/dist/index.html` in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have the following error when using your command : "Cannot read property 'config' of null".
Also I don't have a "dist" folder, just a src and a src/app folder...

Comment: I don't know what could cause the problem with a null reference. The `dist` folder should be created when you run the `ng build` command and it will contain the built application.

Comment: I tried to clone another project and used the ng build then opened the index.html file in the dist folder and it worked perfectly :) ! Thanks for you help Ján!

Comment: That's good to hear. You may also want to use the HashLocationStrategy so when you reload the page in a browser, it still loads the application (index.html): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#location-strategy