# Export Angular single page Application to Static HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for way to convert single page Angular Application to old style html-css-javascript static files, which runs on my pc without any set-up of complicated `node.js` or any `npm`

What I was looking for and came to `Angular` is, I was heavily looking for `Bootstrap-sidebar` with lightweight `css` and `js` but all the examples I could find had large, big size of Javascript files, so I saw Angular had some novel implementation of Sidebar.

I want to convert the Angular sidebar(Angular application) to old style `HTML`, `css` and `js` files so that I can run them without any complex node server.

Is there any way to get the javascript, css and html out of Angular application. I heard of `WebPack` but did not tried, so any suggestion would be appreciated.

If the above process can be done in `React` suggest me a solid way to do that.

**Edit:** What I want is, I want to access the file as `file://path/to/index.html` I  do not want HTTP (`http://localhost/index.html`)

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no "complicated node.js" setup needed to RUN an Angular application. You can deploy an Angular app as a static site. Node.js is only needed for development. If you use the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), then setting up a new project is quite simple. Once you build the app with the CLI (using `ng build` command), you will get an `index.html` and some JavaScript files.

Comment: This `index.html` file do not run or does not render anything just `white` or `blank` page in my browser

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to run the app from your file system without any sort of HTTP server? If you access `index.html` over HTTP (`http://localhost`, not `file://path/to/index.html`), then the JavaScript code should populate `index.html`. Also, https://scully.io/ may be of interest to you.

Comment: Yes - that's what I am looking for - - I want to access `file://path/to/index.html` nothing HTTP (`http://localhost`) - is there any way to do that?

Comment: MAYBE you can do it if you build the Angular app with Scully...but i'm not sure, I never tried it.

Comment: Can the same be done in React? I have built with two commands 1. `npm install` 2. `npm start` inside the folder, and I have `js`, `css`, `html` inside `dist` folder. I am mentioning https://github.com/modularcode/modular-admin-html. The unzipped, and from command line the above can be achieved

Comment: `gatsby` exports static sites

Comment: Does that help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536647/angular-2-without-webserver

Comment: @David I will check it, if it would make css and javascript, html out of Angular Project

Comment: It will be a long time before HTML, CSS and Javascript web pages are ever called "old style".

Comment: @Rob no sorry, take no offence - I am also web developer, but new technologies come, and they do not support previously built technologies - just in my case I can not find any good resource. Well, to request people to help out, you(Read: I) say that.

Comment: What's the use case exactly? Is it just for you, or to redistribute?

Answer (score 16):

**Note**

When compiling an angular project, the result is already a plain html/css/js website. You do not need nodejs to run angular, but, like for any website, you should use a http server. So your problem is rather that you cannot open an angular website from a file, without a webserver.

**Explanation**

Your problem is likely that you have errors in the console when opening the resulting `index.html` from your browser. They come from improved security stadards implemented by browsers (CORS, Strict mime type, access to local files,...). Since you did not provide any error details at all apart from stating that you only have a blank page, here is a basic solution

**Solution**

Try setting base href to `.` when building

```
ng build --prod --base-href=.
```

The website should work without further action on Firefox.

On chrome, you may get one of the following errors

> Access to script at 'file://XXXXXXscripts.js'  from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Or

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

A possible solution is to remove the `type="module"` attribute from all `script` tags at the bottom of `index.html` if using angular 8+.

There are other options to solve CORS related issues on local files, but it involves disabling security on chrome, which is not a good idea.

Comment: This is the correct answer, albeit not being marked by OP!

Comment: I think OP meant SSR. That would be the way to have an "old-school"  HTML/CSS/JS website from an angular app

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple 
You can run npm run build / ng build command.
The build process will transpile all the code into equivalent js code and you can find this transpiled code in "dist" folder of your root project directory.
You can use see there index.html which will be your base html page and other js files or media files which are javascript files.
You can use this content in dist folder to host your website which will be purely html css and js based. You can use nginx or any other server for hosting it.

Answer (score 0):

in Angular you can build your angular application using `ng build` . This will generate a pure js equivalent of the .ts code you wrote.

Comment: `Angular` project can be built by `ng build` but the html file when opened in browser, have nothing, it's just blank. I am looking for something - like converting `Sugarcane` to `Sugar` that can be stored in normal `sacks`, not novel `npm` or `node` things